# install laravel on a system running both windows 10 and ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, windows-10, ubuntu-17.04

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu, and I was already running Windows 10 on my laptop {Toshiba Satellite P55t-A5118}.

Now I want to install and run laravel on my Ubuntu partition, I have installed every software needed, but whenever i run    `vagrant up` i get this error    `VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run VBoxManage --version to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.`

I have searched online and tried almost every solution but yet its still not working.

Comment: And it says after you run `run VBoxManage --version`? I often have issues on Fedora missing kernel-devel/kernel-headers, does it say anything about it?

Comment: After I run `VBoxManage --version` it show's thiis error `WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
  Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
  headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

  You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.1.22_Ubuntur115126`

Comment: So that's an answer you are looking for. Install these packages or google for that error message or update your question. I bet it's missing `linux-headers` as I have the same problem with fresh install on Fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux Ubuntu and Fedora require `kernel-headers` package which is not shipped with fresh installation.

For Ubuntu run: `` sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms ``

For Fedora run: `sudo yum install kernel-devel`

Comment: I have run the command you posted and got this output `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.`
Yet The vagrant has refused to come up

Comment: Try this: `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and see what errors it gives you. And this topic in general: https://askubuntu.com/questions/165544/why-do-guest-additions-need-kernel-headers-in-virtualbox-4-04

Comment: Here is the error am getting `sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found`

Comment: Ok, have you installed VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes i have VirtualBox installed